# Integral for the outer surface area of the part of hyperboloid formed by a hyperbola

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I want to know the surface area of a hyperbola rotates 360 along the y-axis
Hyperbola is infinite, I only want the surface area of a part of the hyperboloid, namely cut by h
[image]

Suppose I know a, b, and h, can anyone show me the internal process to get the surface area(exclusive from the top and bottom circle)?

If I do the following, it won't be a function, how can I use the  surface area of surfaces of revolution
$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$

$x=\sqrt{a^2+a^2\frac{y^2}{b^2}}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT

$a=b$ . Why?

Write x as a function of y for the hyperboloid

The standard formula

$$A= \int_0^h 2 \pi x \sqrt{ 1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2} ~dy  $$

applies.

VISUAL HINT:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, what a=b? and I need to times 2 to your A, right?

Comment: Times 2 for full hyperboloid. You have to yourself look to what the semi-major axes (a,b,c) are and their signs. Giving another visual hint.

Comment: Please take a look at this if you have time https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4586683/surface-area-of-a-one-sheet-hyperboloid-formed-by-rotating-a-sectional-hyperbola

Comment: You can continue here. The semi-axes perpendicular to rotational axis of symmetry should be equal, same symbol is to be used.